# Number of devices supported by one outlet

Tags: receptacle

How can I calculate how many devices I can plug in one outlet?

I am living in Europe and have 220V outlets.

Do I have to check the devices' volts or watts or something else entirely?

Comment: Off topic because use not design. VTC because this belongs on DIY.SE, flagged for migration.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is an engineering theory question - the poster did not ask how many outlets to install, but rather how to perform a calculation.

Comment: I would close it because its all over google, https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Search&q=how+many+outlets+can+I+plug+europe#q=how+many+outlets+can+I+plug+into+an+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Wikipedia's [AC power plugs and sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets) and identify the connector and current rating (amps or 'A')for your sockets.

[image]

*Figure 1. French power socket. Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#/media/File:French-power-socket.jpg).*

The relationship between power, voltage and current is very simple: \$P = VI \$ where P is power (watts or 'W'), V is voltage (volts or 'V') and I is current (amps or 'A).

For example, if your sockets are capable of 10 A then the maximum power you can draw is given by \$ P = VI = 220 \cdot 10 = 2200~W \$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. First you learn the ampacity of the circuit.  Go to the consumer unit and shut off the breaker or pull the fuse that powers that circuit.

The breaker will have a number in amps, typically 6 to 20.  Multiply that by your line voltage (220) and that is how many VA you have available on that circuit.

A bunch of outlets will lose power.  You will need to locate every single one of them which has lost power due to this breaker being off.  You might even give them a name, using breaker space number can seem clever until you move breakers around.

Then you need to measure or resolve the power draw from each unit. Generally the easiest way is via a device such as a Kill-a-Watt, however be careful to measure it when it's actually working, e.g. When your PC is gaming with all the fans running hard, not when it's idle.   You are looking for VA.   If you can't get VA, watts will suffice.

For fixed installation loads, you have to research a bit more, most will have bulbs with obvious VA or watt ratings, or nameplate labels stating same.   If they only give amps, multiply by line voltage to get VA.

If a load is on continuously, multiply its VA by 1.25 to derate it.

The total VA of all the loads should be <= the VA available for the circuit from the breaker/fuse.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: you cannot calculate this.  There are varied local regulations on the subject, and (for instance) in most USA locations a refrigerator's power socket cannot be used to power any second device.   There are code requirements that specify the number of sockets per circuit breaker, that specify maximum current for a particular plug and socket type, and there is SOME guidance from those.

A 10A 220V socket ought to support a 2200W appliance, or a combination of appliances adding up to 2200W, but it is usual for a motor to draw up to three times the nameplate-indicated power when it starts, for a computer to use
less than a quarter the 'rated' power on the label, and there's a subtle difference between 'watts' and 'volt-amps' that is waiting
to trap you.

Your best assurance is to get an energy monitor device (they're inexpensive) and measure energy usage rather than reading energy-use-indicating labels.   Expect to pay $25 (US dollars), and be able to read out volts, amps, volt-amps, watts, and watt-hours (kilowatt-hours).

Comment: You can estimate the total load easily.  Simply add up the nameplate wattage rating of each device connected to that circuit.